# Quick way to open PHP required/included files in Notepad++

Tags: php, notepad++

Is there a keyboard shortcut or plugin to open PHP required or included files in Notepad++? I know that, in Dreamweaver, the command for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, but I can't seem to find an analagous command in Notepad++.

Comment: Maybe you should win your laziness before ask it here.

Comment: how do you win laziness?

Comment: I think that may be Italian for "conquer" (or "overcome")

Comment: ahhh it all makes sense now. Asking a question is kind of a first step for me though.... Typing is hard work.

Comment: Why not just use a real IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse? Notepad++ is great for small projects or quick changes, but as you have found out, it isn't ideal to develop larger set projects in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are interested, I have made a plugin to do exactly this. Put your cursor on the line with the included file and press alt+o. You can download it from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/quickopenplugin/

if there are multiple includes on one line, it will open them all; If you want to explicitly want to open one file, you can also select the filename (and path) to open it.

The plugin handles relative paths :)

Comment: Nice plugin. However it doesnt work for relative paths like '../../path/file.php' as its description claims.

Comment: Were there meanwhile changes concerning relative paths?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, currently there is no similar function supported in Notepad++.

However, you can add it to the [Notepad++ Feature Request Tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=95717&atid=612385).

Answer (score 0):

Are there only to open folder

With relative path on 1 step up parent folder?

Why not like:

```
../../filenmae.ext
../../../../phpfile.php
../../folder1/vbfile.vb
../../../../folder2/delphipascal.pas
```

or

```
././directory/otherfiles.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been coping with the same problem in Notepad++ and finally managed to write a Python script that seems to solve the problem. Warning: it's early alpha with not error handling so I cannot promise 100% functionality, what I can say is, that it works so far. I have put it as shortcut on Alt+Enter and it is a pleasure to work with...

The Python code (you'll need the Python Script plugin by Dave Brotherstone):

```
import re

expr = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9 =_./-]+')
curLine = editor.getCurLine()
console.write('\ncurLine:' + str(curLine)+'\n')
curPos = editor.getCurrentPos()
console.write('curPos:' + str(curPos)+'\n')
curLineIdx = editor.lineFromPosition(curPos)
console.write('curLineIdx:' + str(curLineIdx)+'\n')
curLinIndent = editor.getLineIndentation(curLineIdx)
console.write('curLinIndent:' + str(curLinIndent)+'\n')
curColumn = editor.getColumn(curPos)
console.write('curColumn:' + str(curColumn)+'\n')

firstPart = expr.search(curLine[::-1], len(curLine) - curColumn + curLinIndent)
secondPart = expr.search(curLine, curColumn - curLinIndent)

if firstPart is None or secondPart is None:
    console.write('No filename found')
else:
    fname = firstPart.group(0)[::-1] + secondPart.group(0)
    console.write('Filename: '+fname+'\n')
    notepad.open(re.search(r'\\.*', notepad.getCurrentFilename()[::-1]).group(0)[::-1]+fname)
```

It's my first ever Python script and in every line there is blood and sweat hidden behind each character. I hope it helps you.

Martin